# Can Apache arrow support infinite level nested struct?

Tags: java, c++, pyarrow, apache-arrow

In this Apache arrow documentation page https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Metadata.html
It seems to support it.
Would some post some code to show infinite level nested struct please?
Thanks.

Comment: It is not just c++ Aniket I am adding java and pyarrow in tags. Thanks.

Comment: You probably mean arbitrary levels of nesting and not infinite? Otherwise please explain what you understand with "infinite".

Comment: Hi Uwe, by "infinite" I mean before the data set is created , we don't actually know how many layers will be there. For a given data set it only consists finite number of layers. thanks.

Comment: For a single Arrow Table or RecordBatch, you have to supply the schema fixed with the data. When your overall data set (a collection of RecordBatches) has different nesting levels, you have to merge the schemas after you have written the dataset. There is no placeholder in schemas to specifiy that parts are unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Uwe.

Answer (score 0):

For a single Arrow Table or RecordBatch, you have to supply the schema fixed with the data. When your overall data set (a collection of RecordBatches) has different nesting levels, you have to merge the schemas after you have written the dataset. There is no placeholder in schemas to specifiy that parts are unknown. – Uwe L. Korn